# ID primary key of ONE to MANY related tables jumping numbers with POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, alembic

I am having an issue where the `id` column of tables `users` and `posts` are jumping in increments

`users` and have many `notes` ==> one to many relationship

table `users`

```
id | email | first_name | last_name | password
====================================
1  |1@a.com| john       |       den | 23ojonknen4
2  |2@a.com| jenn       |       dub | rfknkn4j4r4
5  |3@a.com| jai        |       dan | 9jikddjk4nj
```

table `notes`

```
id | note_name | note_content | user_id
=======================================
3  | name one  | this is yes  | 1
4  | name two  | this is no   | 5
```

what is happening is the `id` column of the two tables jump...if there is 3 in id of notes, then next if for users will be 4

how can i fix this issue? or is this normal?

here is the alembic file used to create the schema

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


revision = 'master'
down_revision = None
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None


def upgrade():
    op.create_table(
        'users',
        
        sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
        sa.Column("email", sa.String(254), nullable=False, index=True, unique=True),
        sa.Column("first_name", sa.String(150), nullable=False),
        sa.Column("last_name", sa.String(150), nullable=False),
        sa.Column("password", sa.String(128), nullable=False),
    )

    op.create_table(
        'notes',
        
        sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
        sa.Column("note_name", sa.String(254)),
        sa.Column("note_content", sa.String(254)),
        sa.Column("user_id", sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("users.id")),
    )

def downgrade():
    op.drop_table('users')
    op.drop_table('notes')
```

and here is what i have in my `models.py` file for python to interact with the database

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, Float, Boolean, DateTime, MetaData, Sequence, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

metadata = MetaData()

users = Table(
    "users", metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("email", String(254), nullable=False, index=True, unique=True),
    Column("first_name", String(150), nullable=False),
    Column("last_name", String(150), nullable=False),
    Column("password", String(128), nullable=False),
)


notes = Table(
    "notes", metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("note_name", String(254)),
    Column("note_content", String(254)),
    Column("user_id", Integer, ForeignKey("users.id")),
)
```

so what did i do wrong and how do i fix the issue?

> UPDATE

```
-# \d

                     List of relations
 Schema |          Name          |   Type   |    Owner     
--------+------------------------+----------+--------------
 public | alembic_version        | table    | db_user
 public | pg_stat_statements     | view     | db_user
 public | notes                  | table    | db_user
 public | notes_id_seq           | sequence | db_user
 public | users                  | table    | db_user
 public | users_id_seq           | sequence | db_user
(6 rows)





-# \d users
                                         Table "public.users"
    Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |               Default                
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------
 id           | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 email        | character varying(254)      |           | not null | 
 first_name   | character varying(150)      |           | not null | 
 last_name    | character varying(150)      |           | not null | 
 password     | character varying(128)      |           | not null |  
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)             
    "ix_users_email" UNIQUE, btree (email)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "notes" CONSTRAINT "notes_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)




-# \d notes
                                             Table "public.notes"
       Column        |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                   Default                   
---------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------
 id                  | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('notes_id_seq'::regclass)
 note_name           | character varying(254)      |           |          | 
 note_content        | character varying(254)      |           |                   | 
 user_id             | integer                     |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "notes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "notes_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
```

here is an example query to insert rows into `users` table

```
    query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (nextval('users_id_seq'), :email, :password)"
    return database.execute(query, values={"email": user.email, "password": user.password})
```

here is an example query to insert rows into `notes` table

```
    query = "INSERT INTO notes VALUES (nextval('users_id_seq'), :note_name, :note_content, :user_id)"
    return database.execute(query, values={"note_name": note.name, "note_content": note.content, "user_id": user.id})
```

> could this the issue?
>
> ```
> query = "INSERT INTO notes VALUES (nextval('users_id_seq'),
> :note_name, :note_content, :user_id)"
> ```

**change `nextval('users_id_seq')` to `nextval('notes_id_seq')`?**

Comment: Each table has its own sequence generator, so the ids will be generated independently, unless you are setting the ids in your code.  How are you creating the rows?  A [mre] would be helpful here.  (Also, in your code both tables are assigned to the name `users`, but I assume that's a typo?)

Comment: that was typo...i will post the query to insert user in question now

Comment: Why are you using `nextval()` "manually?" Use the type `serial` instead, and Pg will make those `nextval()` calls for you...

Comment: Also, a `sequence` is not guarantied to have consecutive numbers, there might be holes... (To create a hole, just specify an invalid value for one of the columns, EG NULL for a not null column...)

Comment: Yes, using the users sequence to generate notes ids is the issue.  Postgres will generate the ids automatically, but you need to specify the non-id column names in the insert.  Or just use SQLAlchemy's `insert` function instead of hand-crafting your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix was to fix the `INSERT` query that populates the notes table

FROM

```
query = "INSERT INTO notes VALUES (nextval('users_id_seq'), :note_name, :note_content, :user_id)"
return database.execute(query, values={"note_name": note.name, "note_content": note.content, "user_id": user.id})
```

TO

```
query = "INSERT INTO notes VALUES (nextval('notes_id_seq'), :note_name, :note_content, :user_id)"
return database.execute(query, values={"note_name": note.name, "note_content": note.content, "user_id": user.id})
```

this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

> what is happening is the id column of the two tables jump...if there is 3 in id of notes, then next if for users will be 4

> how can i fix this issue? or is this normal?

Yes, it's totally normal. Auto-generated numbers are not strictly consecutive; the engine makes a *best effort* to make them consecutive, but under conditions of buffering, roll backs, multi-threading, etc. that won't happen in practice.

The key feature you actually need is that those numbers should always be **unique**. As you can see that conditions is satisfied, and that's all you need to maintain data integrity.

Comment: are you saying having the `id` columns of both tables have unique values and jumping based on value in other table is good design? so what happens if i have multiple tables related? have all of them fighting for their turn to count in the `id` column?

Comment: @uberrebu The `INSERT` on the first table provides the the new id as a "returned value" of the SQL call. Then, you use this value to insert in the second table. This way the foreign key relationship is maintained.